# Fotorama - loaded image to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fotorama

I am integrating Fotorama, into a Rails application. The problem is that the image is loaded me right when I visualize. I could help, have any idea ?

```
 <div class='fotorama' data-nav="thumbs" data-width=100%"
 data-ratio="800/600" data-fit="contain">

       <% @fotos.each do |p| %>
         <%= image_tag p.foto%>
         <%#= link_to "Destroy", p, method: :delete %>
       <% end %>
 </div>
```

[image]

Regards.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: photo on the slider is loaded right... I want to center it.